# I need to create a new ETL C# process with large .CSV files to SQL Tables Add/Update records

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, upsert

I need to bring in a number of .CSV files into unique keyed SQL Tables (Table names and column names match from source to target).  I started looking at libs like Cinchoo-ETL, but I need to do an "Upsert" Meaning Update if record is present insert if it's not present. I'm not sure if Cinchoo-ETL or some other lib has this feature built in.

For example lets say the SQL Server Customer table has some records in it, Cust# is a primary Key

Cust#  Name

1       Bob

2       Jack

The CSV file looks something like this:

Cust#,Name

2,Jill

3,Roger

When the ETL program runs it needs to update Cust# 2 from Jack to Jill  and insert a new cust# 3 record for Roger.

Speed reusability is important as there will be 80 or so different tables, some of the tables can have several million records in them.

Any ideas for a fast easy way to do this?  Keep in mind I'm not a daily developer so examples would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, it is a two step process. (1) Load *.csv files into a staging table. (2) After that T-SQL `MERGE` statement will do upsert.

Comment: If you're not an experienced developer and don't need a ton of business logic: I would suggest using something like SSIS to import the data using a job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are describing something than can be done with a tool I developped. It's called Fuzible ([www.fuzible-app.com](http://www.fuzible-app.com)) : in Synchronization mode, it allows you to choose the behavior of the target table (allow INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) and your Source can be any CSV file and your target, any database.
You can contact me from the website if you need an how-to.
The software is free :)

What you have to do is to create a Job with your CSV path as a Source connection, then your Database as the Target connection.
Choose the "Synchronization" mode, which, by opposition with the "Replication" mode will compare Source and Target data.
Then, you can write as many queries as you want (one for each CSV file) like this :
MyOutputTable:SELECT * FROM MyCSVFile.CSV

No need to write more complex queries if both CSV and database table shares the same schema (same columns)

The software should be able to do the rest :) Update rows than need to be updated and create new rows if required.

Comment: The Fuzible package is met all of my needs and saved me from a bunch of unnecessary coding!  It even manages to automate the transfer directly partners SFTP Server.  I have a daily and a Monthly process running easily handling files of over 30 million records.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in a recent SSIS job. I load the data to a temp table just use a regular SQL query to perform this comparison. This may be cumbersome on tables with lots of fields.

```
-- SEE DIFFERENCES FOR YOUR AMUSEMENT
SELECT *
FROM Accounts a
    INNER JOIN
        DI_Accounts da
    ON a.CustomerNumber = da.CustomerNumber AND (
            a.FirstName <> da.FirstName
        )


-- UPDATE BASED ON DIFFERENCES
UPDATE a
    SET
        a.FirstName = a.FirstName
    FROM Accounts a
    INNER JOIN
        DI_Accounts da
    ON a.ModelId = da.ModelId AND (
            a.FirstName <> da.FirstName
        )
```

Comment: Does your table prefix "DI_" stands for something like "data ingest" or "data in"?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you take a look at the nuget package [ETLBox](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ETLBox/) and the necessary extension packages for Csv & Sql Server ([ETLBox.Csv](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ETLBox.Csv) + [ETLBox.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ETLBox.SqlServer)).

This would allow you to write a code like this:

```
//Create the components

CsvSource source = new CsvSource("file1.csv");

SqlConnectionManager conn = new SqlConnectionManager("..connection_string_here..");

DbMerge dest = new DbMerge(conn, "DestinationTableName");
dest.MergeProperties.IdColumns.Add(new IdColumn() { IdPropertyName = "Cust#" });
dest.MergeMode = MergeMode.Full; //To create the deletes
dest.CacheMode = CacheMode.Partial; //Enable for bigger data sets

//Linking
source.LinkTo(dest);

//Execute the data flow
Network.Execute(source);
```

This code snipped would do the corresponding inserts/updates & deletes into the database table for one file.  Make sure that the header names match exactly with the column names in your database table (case-sensitive). For bigger data sets you need to enable the partial cache, to avoid having all data loaded into Memory.

It will use dynamic objects under the hood (ExpandoObject). You can find more information about the merge and the tool on the website ([www.etlbox.net](https://www.etlbox.net))

The only downside is that ETLBox is not open source. But the package allows you to work with data sets up to 10.000 rows to check if it suits your needs.